# Button created on HTML5 App using Intel XDK not working

Tags: javascript, html, appmobi, intel-xdk

I am creating an HTML5 App using Intel XDK. In my first page (page_0) there are options to  select the conversion style. When choose 1st option, it goes to page_1. There are some input boxes and buttons. When I hit calculate, it calculates the expression but immediately returns back to page_0. The button code is like this:

```
<a class="button" href="#" style="position: relative; z-index: 2;" data-appbuilder-object="button" data-position="static" data-transition="slide" id="calc_r_sft"   onclick="getValues_r_sft();">Calculate</a>
```

How to avoid this automatic navigation and let the user stay in the calculation page (Page_1)?

Answer (score 3):

Modify

```
onclick="getValues_r_sft();"
```

to

```
onclick="getValues_r_sft(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using App Starter. (http://appstarter.app-framework-software.intel.com/).

I could not reproduce the problem. I started a new app, created a 2nd page. Added a button to the page. Then I tried the app in the previewer. When I click on the button, it stays on the same page. This is the HTML I generated.

Button

Answer (score 0):

try using `<div>` instead of `<a>`